# How to visualize a data like point (x,y) and for each point there is some temperature associated to it

Tags: python, holoviews, datashader

```
df.head()
```

|  | x | y | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14.15 | 49.58 | 47.5 |
| 1 | 13.30 | 34.77 | 41.4 |
| 2 | 12.53 | 42.70 | 32.7 |
| 3 | 11.74 | 45.77 | 34.6 |
| 4 | 18.98 | 42.70 | 70.7 |

```py
opts1 = hv.opts.RGB(width=1700, height=800)
df_ds = datashade(
    hv.Points(df),
    cmap=cc.CET_L4,
    kdims=["x", "y"],
    label="xy cordinate values",
    colorbar=True,
    min_alpha=0.3,
).opts(tools=["hover", "box_zoom"])
df_ds.opts(opts1)
```

[image]

Where I can show the temperature value and associate a color map to the temperature?

I looked at the docs but could not figure it out.

Comment: Have you considered using temperature as a colour, with the (x, y) values in the corresponding axes. You might have to use a different package...

Comment: You can definitely do this with holoviews and datashader. See these docs on the rasterize function: https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html#holoviews-operations-for-datashading

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I am unable to figure it out, I am new to this ..would you please help me on this.

Comment: Can you post what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck? If you’re able to create the points with hv.Points you should be able to follow the rest of that tutorial to use rasterize. If you get stuck, [edit] your question to include your code and show us what went wrong.

Comment: opts1 = hv.opts.RGB(width=1700, height=800)
df_ds=datashade(hv.Points(df),cmap = cc.CET_L4,  kdims=['x', 'y'], label='xy cordinate values', colorbar = True, min_alpha=0.3 ).opts(tools=['hover', 'box_zoom'])
df_ds.opts(opts1), where I can show the temperature value ?